# how to get more information about a SQL warning in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to access to an Oracle DB in PHP, but it throws me the following error:

`Warning: oci_execute(): in PATH_TO_FILE.php on line XXX` with no more information...

I'm doing the following on that line...

```
oci_free_statement($stmt);
$consulta="LOAD DATA CONCURRENT LOCAL INFILE 'files/data.csv' 
          INTO TABLE PRUEBA_SMS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
          (@FECHA,NODO,SERVICIO,VALOR) 
 SET FECHAHORAINF=TO_DATE(@FECHA,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')";
$stmt=oci_parse($conexion, $consulta);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

Is there some way to know more about that warning and why is this failing?

**UPDATE**: Well, after researching I think that the problem is that the `LOAD DATA INFILE` procedure is not compatible with a SQL database, only if it was a MySQL one. I tried to launch the command into the Oracle SQL Plus program and it throws me the next error...

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LOAD DATA ... " Rest of the line ignored
```

Regards!

Comment: what is the `format` of `@FECHA`?

Comment: It's a String, that's why I use the `TO_DATE()`, because in the DB that field is a `DATE` type.

Comment: I asked what is the format of `date` in `string`, if it anything other than `DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss` `query will fail.

Comment: Ooops, sorry I misunderstood you. The format is correct, It's not that point.

Answer (score 0):

If your error_reporting level is set to E_WARNING you should see a warning message in the Apache error_log with the full Oracle error stack.

Comment: The error_reporting level can be configured to all with the line `error_reporting(-1);`? Because I don't see any warning on the error.log

Comment: I don't know the meaning of the -1 value, I do use error_reporting(E_ALL) in my applications but I think in this situation error_reporting(E_WARNING) is enough.

Comment: The -1 value is the same as E_ALL. By the way, in my `php_error.log` file only appears the same as in the PHP console: `[06-Aug-2015 11:59:32 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  oci_execute():  in PATH_TO_ARCHIVE.php on line XXX`

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle try with SQL-Loader [sqlldr]

You can find usefull examples here (and all over internet)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/aload.htm

Saludos.